# Should I bring a Crowbar to Dracula's Castle?

Tags: dead-cells

The description for the Crowbar says it inflicts critical hits when hitting bestial enemies. Would the enemies added in the [Return to Castlevania DLC](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2101430/Dead_Cells_Return_to_Castlevania/) be considered bestial? The Dead Cells wiki has a list of enemies [the Crowbar](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Crowbar) deals critical damage to, but I can't tell if it's been updated for the new Castlevania DLC.

In other words, if I bring a Crowbar to the Castlevania biomes, am I going to be dealing critical damage to everything?